# Retrieve Design Matrix from DMatrix Instance in xgboost

Tags: python, xgboost

In xgboost, I'm doing something like

```
import numpy as np
import xgboost as xgb
y = np.arange(10)
X = np.arange(20).reshape(10, 2)
dtrain = xgb.DMatrix(X, y, feature_names=["x1", "x2"])
```

If I want to extract the y values as an array from dtrain, I can do

```
y = dtrain.get_label()
```

Is there any way to extract the X values as an array from dtrain?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so. With your `DMatrix` `dtrain`, you can see:

```
dir(dtrain)

['__class__', '__del__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__le__', '__lt__', '__module__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__qualname__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_feature_names', '_feature_types', '_init_from_csc', '_init_from_csr', '_init_from_npy2d', 'feature_names', 'feature_types', 'get_base_margin', 'get_float_info', 'get_label', 'get_uint_info', 'get_weight', 'handle', 'num_col', 'num_row', 'save_binary', 'set_base_margin', 'set_float_info', 'set_group', 'set_label', 'set_uint_info', 'set_weight', 'slice']
```

The best I can find is

```
dtrain.feature_names
```

which will return your `["x1", "x2"]`. `dtrain.feature_types` is somewhat helpful, and you can take slices like `dtrain.slice(range(3))`, but this still isn't what you're looking for.